# TooManyRequestsException: Rate exceeded. while creating many cognito users at a time from node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS sdk in my NodeJS Application to Create the Cognito Users.

I am tring to create 100 user in one go using adminCreateUser method.

Is there Max limit to create user per second? I am getting Too many requests
error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/limits.html

AdminCreateUser is 5 RPS. I would suggest just slowing down the rate at which you call the API.

Comment: Amazon can increase this.  I requested it to be increased to 100 and they gave me 50.